# How I can run mysql query automatically in every 1 hour?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I've integer value in my database and I want to decrease it with every passing hour. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have used MySQL then please create cronJOB.
if you have used SQL then please create Scheduler.

And set time and execute stored procedure.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to decrement the value.  You can just store the base value and create a view to calculate the value one the fly. Something like this:

```
create table hourly (
    base_value int,
    starttime datetime
);
```

Then:

```
create view v_hourly
    select base_value - timestampdiff(hour, starttime, now())
    from hourly;
```

The alternative is to set up a job that runs each hour to decrement the value, but that is not necessary.

Comment: actually if the integer become zero i have to set another value to 0

Comment: Your right you should create a MySQL event or cronjob for a simple decreasing value those inner processes or threads in MySQL or OS are not "cheap"..

Comment: i actually want to change it in database

Comment: @BilalArshad in that case your question had a incomplete user case i advice to review it and [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55043716/edit) your question, ideally with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: question is complete you have to understand it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the mysql event scheduler. You can find more information and examples here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-event.html